# Objective C - Image from camera to set on UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, uibutton, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to set image from camera to set on my button but it did not accepting cropped image by default it sets to original image width and height which was captured by camera and because of this image looks shrink from top to bottom .

When I click on `UIButton` camera opens and then after image captured it shows on this `UIButton`

```
- (IBAction)ProfImageBtnCliked:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [picker setAllowsEditing:YES];
    picker.delegate = self;
    if ([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear] || [UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront]  )
    { 
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"No Camera Available"delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show]; 
    }
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
    NSData *dataForImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"], 1.0);
    [ProfImgButton setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:dataForImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    ProfImgButton.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    ProfImgButton.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    ProfImgButton.clipsToBounds=YES;
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(200,200);
    NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([self imageWithImage [UIImage imageWithData:dataForImage] scaledToSize:constraint], 0);
    NSLog(@"Size of Image(bytes):%lu",(unsigned long)[imgData length]);
    NSString *imageString = [imgData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];
    NSLog(@"%@",imageString);

    //assign base64 image to image string
    Base64ImageString=[imageString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];    
}

//reduce image size
-(UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the original image taken from your camera in your code here

```
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
    NSData *dataForImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"], 1.0);
    [ProfImgButton setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:dataForImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

while you are resizing the image below

```
CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(200,200);
    NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([self imageWithImage [UIImage imageWithData:dataForImage] scaledToSize:constraint], 0);
    NSLog(@"Size of Image(bytes):%lu",(unsigned long)[imgData length]);
```

This data is not used anywhere. You are not setting it on your ProfImgButton

All you need to do is set the resized imagedata to your button

```
[ProfImgButton setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imgData] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Can downvoter please mention the reason of downvoting it?

Comment: Log the bytes of the image before and after resizing. Before setting the image to UIButton you can check the image by placing a break point on the line and bringing cursor over it. Add this line to view your image.
After resizing the image set image to uiimage
`UIImage *resizedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];`
One more thing i don't think so its croping your image its just resizing.

Comment: but i want image cropped. when camera is open after capture image i get one square rectangle to crop image i want but after crop i cant see any changes on UIButton image shows full

Comment: Instead of getting original image you can get edited image from UIImagePickerController

`UIImage *image = [info objecyForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];`

Answer (score 0):

Your code of cropping is wrong!

Write like this:-

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
        {
            [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
               CGSize size = CGSizeMake(200,200);

              UIImage *originalImage=UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"], 1.0);

              //CROP image code
               UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);   
              [originalImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
              UIImage *croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
              UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

            //now assign image to button 
            [ProfImgButton setImage:croppedImage  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            ProfImgButton.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
            ProfImgButton.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
            ProfImgButton.clipsToBounds=YES;


            NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(croppedImage , 0);
            NSLog(@"Size of Image(bytes):%lu",(unsigned long)[imgData length]);
            NSString *imageString = [imgData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];
            NSLog(@"%@",imageString);


        //assine base64 image to image string
            Base64ImageString=[imageString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];    
  }
```

Comment: Log shows this error after changing to originalImage `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteMutableData drawInRect:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x189b6d80'`

Comment: Every thing cannot be spoon feed to you, use your brain. I am not here to give you exact code, just told you the logic and where you are making wrong.Now, use your brain .

Comment: "If coding hangs your brain", then you are in wrong profession man! Just a piece of advice.